# How I can show a preview from my form to customer?

Tags: javascript, html

I want make a form, and on the left side I want show a small preview of this information but I don't know how.

I'd like to have something similar to the preview capabilities here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Two way data binding is what you are looking for. Use angular for example. Very simple example is here:

```
<div ng-app>
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
    <div>Hello {{name}}!</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anandmanisankar/L6nofag6/.

There are other ways to achieve what you want, but two way data binding is IMHO the easiest.